# Do users expect an 'undo' feature in web applications?

Tags: web-app, research, undo

We are designing a web application, which is basically a drawing tool for processes. My hypothesis is that the user would like to be able to Undo an action.

My question is if there is some research in having an Undo in web applications. Are the users used to this functionality when browsing the web?

So far, I have seen undo function in applications like:

- Inbox

[image: Inbox]

- Draw.io
- Stack Overflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best design for 'undo' in rich web apps?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/62783/best-design-for-undo-in-rich-web-apps)

Comment: The question is regarding the design of the "Undo" functionality. It's not a duplicate of the aforementioned question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[See this very related question for a detailed answer on implementing undo](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/62783/best-design-for-undo-in-rich-web-apps).

[Here is a focused article on Model-View-Controller implementation of undo (which can be applied to web-apps)](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2471643&seqNum=5).

If your web application allows for constant manipulation of data (i.e. a drawing tool), undo should be a high priority.

My feeling is there's a lack of "research" out there on this subject, because the same rules apply here as do to desktop apps. Look for research on undo broadly and apply those rules to your web app.

It's a natural progression of computing:

- Users expect undo support in their desktop apps
- Web app usage has increased dramatically as they improve in functionality (Google suite, Office 365, Slack)
- Users expect the same undo support in web apps

Would your application have undo if it was designed for a desktop? If so, implement it in your web app.